# xcode password text field shows % sign instead of dot in IOS7

Tags: ios7, xcode5

For some reason, when I run my app in IOS7 (it was built for IOS6 long ago) it shows the % sign when i enter text in my textfield instead of the usual "dot". It works fine in IOS6, but in IOS7 it has this annoying thing. I'm using xcode5.

It shows % signs when you enter text, but when it looses focus, it becomes dots. When it gets focus again, it turns into % signs again.
I cant seem to find info on this, so have not been able to find any solution/reason for this :/

Anybody know about this?